# why i am getting "An argument named "sku" is not expected here" ,what is wrong here

Tags: azure, terraform

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip_bastion_hub" {
  name                = var.public_ip_for_bastion_host_hub
  location            = var.Location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_hub
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_bastion_host" "bastion-host_hub" {
  name                = var.bastion_host_name_for_hub
  location            = var.Location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_hub
  sku                 = "Standard"
  ip_connect_enabled  = "true"

  ip_configuration {
    name                 = "configuration"
    subnet_id            = azurerm_subnet.hub_subnet1.id
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pip_bastion_hub.id
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_public_ip.pip_bastion_hub,azurerm_resource_group.rg_spoke2]
}
```

│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 137, in resource "azurerm_bastion_host" "bastion-host_hub":
│  137:   sku                 = "Standard"
│
│ An argument named "sku" is not expected here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **upgrade** your azurem provider. Sku was added in version [2.88](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v2.88.0/CHANGELOG.md).